# How to import data into SQL.js?

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

I found the following library to store data in a database with javascript.
https://github.com/kripken/sql.js
Now i'd like to use it to store data for an app by storing the data in a file. 
Unfortunatly it only supports exportData, but nothing to import, but otherwise, it works fine.
So, does someone have an idea, how i could hijack this thing, to get the data back into the library? So that i can load the exported data from a  file (Filewriting in phonegap possible) and load it back into the library. When i export it, i get a unit8 Arrray in the sqlite 3 format.

Comment: can you plz clarify your requirement in detail.

Comment: Yes FileReading and FileWriting is posible with phonegap. i think you want to store some data in file and retrieve that file's data. Am i right.

Comment: yes, but sql.js doesn't have a function for that. Now i hope that theres a variable or something where the data is stored, that i could just overwrite.

Comment: Is that compulsory to use sql.js for writing and reading to file

Comment: no, but i'd be very practical, because databases make storing data much easier.

Comment: It means you just want to store data in database and retrieve as and when you want right?

Comment: yes, but it needs to be in javascript, be stored after the app is closed and work on IOS, WP and Android.

Comment: yes you can use phonegap storage api for that. data will be preserved after your app is closed. [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: but it says in Supported Platforms that WP is not supported

Comment: so you want to make it for windows platform right

Comment: Have you tried with [https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin](https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL.js can read database from disk; so it's enough just to reinit your request.

```
    Sql.open db_file, {}, (err, db) ->
      throw err if err
      db.exec 'SELECT * FROM cars;', (err, result) ->
        assert.deepEqual [{"id":"1","color":"red"},{"id":"2","color":"blue"},{"id":"3","color":"green"}], result
        done()
```

I copied this from their test files... So maybe will help you!